# How to assign values on Master Page load?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I want to create Image Slide for my site like This site http://www.martynrussell.co.uk/default3.aspx?MenuID=1 below featured properties.

Content of this image are dynamic. Some times whole content will change or some time the position Properties are change.

I am able to make content dynamic.

Images are coming from body onLoad like this.

```
<body id="pageid1" onload="SetupFeaturedProperty(1,['http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1076-1.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1076-2.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1076-3.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1076-4.jpg']);SetupFeaturedProperty(2,['http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/122-1.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/122-2.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/122-3.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/122-4.jpg']);SetupFeaturedProperty(3,['http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/38-1.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/38-2.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/38-3.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/38-4.jpg']);SetupFeaturedProperty(4,['http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/918-1.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/918-2.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/918-3.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/918-4.jpg']);SetupFeaturedProperty(5,['http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1039-1.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1039-2.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1039-3.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1039-4.jpg']);">
```

Now My Problem Is how can assign this to on Master page onload. because images order are changing dynamically.

Yesterday Image order is like this.

```
<body id="pageid1" onload="SetupFeaturedProperty(1,['http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/918-1.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/918-2.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/918-3.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/918-4.jpg']);SetupFeaturedProperty(2,['http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/665-1.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/665-2.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/665-3.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/665-4.jpg']);SetupFeaturedProperty(3,['http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/38-1.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/38-2.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/38-3.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/38-4.jpg']);SetupFeaturedProperty(4,['http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/122-1.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/122-2.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/122-3.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/122-4.jpg']);SetupFeaturedProperty(5,['http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1076-1.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1076-2.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1076-3.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1076-4.jpg']);">
```

And Today's Image order like this

```
<body id="pageid1" onload="SetupFeaturedProperty(1,['http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1076-1.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1076-2.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1076-3.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1076-4.jpg']);SetupFeaturedProperty(2,['http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/122-1.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/122-2.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/122-3.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/122-4.jpg']);SetupFeaturedProperty(3,['http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/38-1.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/38-2.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/38-3.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/38-4.jpg']);SetupFeaturedProperty(4,['http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/918-1.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/918-2.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/918-3.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/918-4.jpg']);SetupFeaturedProperty(5,['http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1039-1.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1039-2.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1039-3.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1039-4.jpg']);">
```

Please suggest me how can i manage this. How can i assign values at run time like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ContetPages will have different images and you want to trigger the SetupFeaturedProperty-function from MasterPage? If so, try following:

MasterPage.master

```
 ...

    <head>

      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" id="Headers">

      </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
      <script language=javascript>
        function mp_onload()
        {
          if(window.body_onload != null)
          window.body_onload();
        }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="mp_onload();">

    ...
```

If you have a content page that may require an onload event, then you just need to create a function called `body_onload` in Headers content area of each page that requires it. it'll get called from MasterPage automatically.

Default.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Headers" Runat="Server">
  <script language="javascript">
    function body_onload()
    {
      SetupFeaturedProperty(1,['http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1076-1.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1076-2.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1076-3.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1076-4.jpg']);SetupFeaturedProperty(2,['http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/122-1.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/122-2.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/122-3.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/122-4.jpg']);SetupFeaturedProperty(3,['http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/38-1.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/38-2.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/38-3.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/38-4.jpg']);SetupFeaturedProperty(4,['http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/918-1.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/918-2.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/918-3.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/918-4.jpg']);SetupFeaturedProperty(5,['http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1039-1.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1039-2.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1039-3.jpg', 'http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1039-4.jpg']);
    }
  </script>
</asp:Content>
```

http://blog.thewightstuff.net/blog/2007/03/using-body-onload-with-aspnet-20.html

**Edit**: According to your comment on how to init the function in codebehind(untested):

```
Dim allImageUrls As New List(Of String)(New String() {"http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1076-1.jpg", "http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1076-2.jpg", "http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1076-3.jpg", "http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/1076-4.jpg", "http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/122-1.jpg", "http://www.brightlogic-estateagents.co.uk/MRUS/upload/122-2.jpg"})
If allImageUrls.Count <> 0 Then
   Dim arrayBuilder As New System.Text.StringBuilder("[")
   For Each imageUrl As String In allImageUrls
       arrayBuilder.Append("'").Append(imageUrl).Append("',")
   Next
   arrayBuilder.Length -= 1 ' remove last comma '
   arrayBuilder.Append("]")

   Dim jsVarImgUrls As String = arrayBuilder.ToString
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("allImageURLs", jsVarImgUrls)
End If
```

Then you can easily access that array from your onload-function, f.e.:

```
OnLoad = "SetupFeaturedProperty(1, allImageURLs);"
```

Comment: Thanks For your reply it's worked for me. Arguments of this method can be change after some time these are not static values. can please help me and let me know how can i pass values from code behind to this java script method